# Rails: Importing CDN files vs using the assets for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, performance

I'm a brand new developer (~3-4 weeks), and I've been using rubymine to build my ruby on rails application. I installed a plugin for bootstrap-4, and the automatic template it gave me for a bootstrap page included the following lines of code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've spent the last 2 hours reading up on CDN files and the assets pipeline, but I still am not understanding what best practices here are: should I remove these CDN files and replace them with gems and/or 'require' lines in the assets pipeline, or should I leave them here? I know this probably depends on my goal, but my goal is simply to give my website style without causing large lags in loading time. One of my pages will have lots of onclick functionality and api calls, and in the previous version of the application, things were getting slowed down (not sure if it was because of the javascript, but my gut tells me that it probably had something to do with it).

In sum, I want simplicity, and I want to understand my code, haha. Should I keep these CDN lines of code or should I replace them with something in the asset pipeline?

Cheers, Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **CDN** puts your content in many places at once, providing superior
>   coverage to your users.

*You can read more about them [here](https://www.incapsula.com/cdn-guide/what-is-cdn-how-it-works.html)*.

It is better in the above case that you use **CDN(Content Delivery Network)** as it will improve your page's load time. It is only the first time a js,css files specified in the link, script tags would get cached from the nearest location and from next request onwards they will be loaded from browser's cache.

On first request as the js/css will be loading from the nearest geographical location the load time will be less.

**Example:**

Consider your app being hosted in US, and a user accessing it from India.
If you were using CDN, it will try to load the asset from the nearest geographical location where as if you weren't using CDNs then it would load from US and so more load time.

In general it's better to use assets if:

- it is not a common css/js or it is your own asset
- if you feel its going to change atleast once a day/week/month

Whenever you do asset precompile rails appends a hash code to the names of all the assets, its rails way of maintaining versions of your assets. By default the assets will get cached based on your app's caching setting and the app will use the cached version until a new version of asset is available. The only problem, it will always load for the first time from your app's hosting location, so slightly more load time.

But you can use **AWS S3**, which allows you to store your assets in S3 bucket and then **create your own CDN** from the S3 bucket. You can read about **syncing assets** to S3 using **asset_sync gem** [here](https://github.com/AssetSync/asset_sync) and about creating **AWS Cloudfront**(CDN) from S3 bucket [here](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-s3/doc/cloudfront-setup/).

Comment: Sweet answer! So basically, given my meager goals, I should definitely use a CDN. No need to re-invent the wheel until I get better wheel-crafting abilities. Thanks!

Comment: One more question about this: what happens to SCSS and SASS with the CDN files? I just found another stackoverflow question/answer that said CDN only serves CSS - is this true?

Comment: @michaelsking1993 yes it would not make sense to serve scss even if it was possible as everytime you load it from CDN you would have to compile it and use css as browsers cannot understand scss or sass. You can use scss and less in rails with the help some gems. Rails will compile and compress them for you and serve it as css thereby improving your website's performance. With the help of asset_sync gem you can upload your compiled and compressed assets from s3 buckets with the help of Cloudfront.